# Would this character still have to be loyal to the Night's Watch?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

Beware this post contains spoilers!

> At the end of Season 6 Episode 2, Jon Snow awakes from the dead and the episode ends.

Now, the Night's Watch holds you loyal & responsible for your entire life.  If you desert, you are killed for disobeying your oath to protect the realm with the Night's Watch.

> But in this very rare case, Jon Snow technically already gave his life (1st life) to the Night's Watch, and now he is on his second life (again, technically)  Is there something written in some very old book stating you will give your entire life, before and after death, to the Night's Watch?  Or will this incident still be considered his first life?  Or can he just abandon (abandon might be a poor word, maybe a better choice of words would be 'make his own choices') the Night's Watch without any circumstance?

Hopefully, this season gets even crazier!

Comment: Wow, I never cared to think about that but this really seems to be something that genuinely puzzles people. ;-)

Comment: To be fair, the question title is a bit of a spoiler in itself...

Comment: @DaveM I tried to fix it a little.